# How to handle non-generic errors in python?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a loop that I run via the statement:
`os.system('python3 wrapper.py')` which generates some files.

And every so often it hits an error such as this:

```
pybullet.error: Cannot load URDF file.
Error: InMemoryFile::~InMemoryFileIO (numAllocs 1 numFrees 2
```

This message is printed to the terminal. I would like to know how I can automatically get my code to start running again so long as the number of files generated is less than 20.

I tried the following:

```
while numberOfFilesGeneratedByLoop != 20:
     os.system('python3 wrapper.py')
```

However, it was still stopped by the same error.

Comment: Why are you running a Python script using a system command?  Why not just run the Python code directly?  What is the code in `wrapper.py`?  I don't know if anyone is going to know what's going on with your code if you aren't showing it to us.  In the code you show, it appears that you have an infinite loop, as the value of `numberOfFilesGeneratedByLoop` is never going to be updated by the code in the loop.

Comment: 1. I'm not running the python code directly because I want to be able to run it without touching the computer. 
2. The code in wrapper.py is irrelevant to the question, as it's a general question and applicable to any situation where there's a non-generic error message. 
3. I want to know how to rerun a piece file when a certain message is printed to the terminal. I'm fairly new to python, but it's pretty simple in other languages. 

If you don't know the answer, allow someone else to. I didn't see anything about non-generic error handling in python when I searched stack overflow.

Comment: The thing about using `os.system` because you want to run it "without touching the computer" is nonsensical.  "Non generic error" isn't a thing.  If you shared your code people could show you exactly how to fix your problem -- but the vague handwavy answer you're looking for is: *don't use `os.system`, call  your Python code as actual Python code so you can handle errors natively in Python.*

Comment: Hey man, I'm not stopping anyone else from answering.  The issue I have with what you're asking is that the error message you show is not something I've ever seen come from running `os.system()`, so I assumed that that error was coming from whatever it is you're running.  I don't know what `"pybullet`" is, but that seems to be the source of your problem, and that can only becoming from the code in `wrapper.py`.  If you want to know how to keep going after such an error, just put a `try/catch` around your call to `os.system()`...but you have an infinite loop, so then your code will never stop.

Comment: @Samwise It seems that you're getting confused by semantics. Often times in python, we use Built-in exceptions to report error conditions. Since you're not familiar with them, you might want to read up https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: ...actually, I don't think `os.system()` will be throwing an exception in that case.  So you should already have an infinite loop.  We need to know more if we're going to offer you real help.

Comment: Like I said, the exceptions are non-generic, meaning that they're coming from a program that I'm using. It's a simulator called pybullet, which is imported into python. I'm basically trying to make an if statement that runs when this error is printed to the terminal.

Comment: Take a look at the `subprocess` module.  It gives you way more control over the execution of an external command.  It lets you redirect `stdout` and `stderr`.  You could get the result code, and if it isn't `0`, then look at what is in `stderr` to determine what went wrong.  I didn't understand your question because I thought there was more to it than asking "how does os.system() work?".  That's really all you're asking here the way I see it.  Check out `subprocess.call()` or other functions in the `subprocess` module. - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: No worries, @CryptoFool somebody answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 file.py > outputLog.txt`

Log the output of your file to a .txt file, and then you can read through it. You can conditionally re-run your wrapper if the non-generic error statements are in outputLog.txt.